# handle when user turns off push notification permission in android?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-permissions

What will be the FCM(GCM) response in that case if the user has turned off the notification permission. As per FCM documentation we will get a NotRegistered response if the app is uninstalled or app is not configured to receive push messages. Does this mean that we get we will get NotRegistered response when user has turned off the permission.